# SSMS- SQL Create JSON String with nested array of multiple column of same group

Tags: sql, sql-server

On the following table I am trying to create a row of JsonString which have set of array for the individual group. I am not able to find a way to get the expected result.

[image]

```
Select GroupID, Name, RecordNumber 
from Table
Group by GroupID, Name, RecordNumber
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: @eshirvana I am using v18.4

Comment: @eshirvana it is SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2):

since you can't have dynamic root you have to do it manually :

```
select GroupID
        -- adding dynamic root to JSON string
      , '{"' + CAST(GroupID AS VARCHAR(100)) + '":' + 
      (
          select Name, RecordNumber
          from yourtable g2
          where g2.GroupID = g.GroupID
          for json auto
      ) 
      + '}' as JsonString
from yourtable g
group by GroupID
```

Comment: got you! Thank you for answering my question, this is what I wanted to see as a result.